# Visual Studio не видит каталог библиотек

Tags: visual-studio, include

День добрый.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Скопировал существующий проект, в котором включены стандартные библиотеки (`#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <tchar.h>` и т п). Но программа пишет "Не удается найти источник файла `stdio.h`" и т.п.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где в настройках проекта должно это прописываться.
В остальных проектах у меня такой проблемы не было.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с этим: [Неустранимая ошибка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/et4zwx34.aspx) обратите внимание на *Файл не включен в путь поиска компилятора*

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, С этим я ознакомился. Тут суть не в том - вызывается все правильно. Он именно не находит эти файлы почему-то.

Comment: Добавлю, возможно ошибка может быть в этом. Копируемый проект создавался на Visual Studio 2013, а запускаю я на версии 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, при создании проекта, если копировали в свой уже созданный проект, Вы указали в его свойствах не Empty project, а Precompiled Headers, попробуйте создать пустой проект и скопировать туда код.

Comment: Я скопировал уже готовый проект. Который на другой машине работал (правда не у меня). Отличие в версиях студий - там 2013, у меня 2010.  Но где параметр влияющий на исходные каталоги библиотек - я не могу найти

Comment: При различии студий выдаст ошибку несовместимости версий компилятора. Пример у меня: создавал проект в 2015 студии, запускал в 2013. Ошибка выдала, что нужна версия компилятора 140v, в 13 стоит 120v. Посмотрите код ошибки, возможно MSDN подскажет. Посмотрите правильно ли вызывается подключение библиотеки. Обычно могут забыть указать <stdio.h> скобки и ставят "stdio.h", это разные вещи, при кавычках ищет локально.

Comment: ну да, тут тоже 120v стояло. Я пересоздал проект с нуля. Попробую так.  Такой вопрос еще - если dll собрана на 13й студии, она должна все равно подгружаться и нормально запускаться из 10й?